# Checking not required field is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a child input component and i want to create a test in case that input is required or not. but the test fail in the line to check if it is false

> expect(fieldNotRequired).toBeFalsy();

What is wrong here?

```
test("Form Field Input", () => {
  render(
    <FieldTestWrapper>
      <InputField
        name={"required"}
        label={"required"}
        type={"text"}
        data-test-id="required"
        required
      />
      <InputField
        name={"not-required"}
        label={"not-required"}
        type={"text"}
        data-test-id="not-required"
      />
    </FieldTestWrapper>
  );

  const fieldRequired = screen.getByTestId("required");
  const fieldNotRequired = screen.getByTestId("not-required");

  expect(fieldRequired).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(fieldNotRequired).toBeInTheDocument();

  expect(fieldRequired).toBeTruthy();
  expect(fieldNotRequired).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
expect(fieldRequired).toHaveClass("required");
```

or even click some submit button or something and after that try some validation like

```
expect(screen.getByText('Field is required')).toBeTruthy();
```

just if you have any kind of validation like that, of course.